# Can't run "sudo lvdisplay" command on RHEL 5.4

Tags: linux, environment-variables, lvm

I want to run "sudo lvdisplay" command on RHEL 5.4 , but it replying that sudo: lvdisplay: command not found. If I run "sudo /sbin/lvm lvdisplay". it running , what should I do ?
please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe redhat doesn't have this alias script.

You can add a shell alias, create a script or just run the cmdline you're mentioned.